# Iterate through multidimensional array, grabbing values to be inserted into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, loops, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```html
array(88) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["currency_pair"]=>
    string(6) "BTCCAD"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "Buy"
    ["trade_id"]=>
    string(5) "34637"
    ["order_id"]=>
    string(8) "51214063"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(10) "0.03296178"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "271.83"
    ["total"]=>
    string(4) "8.96"
    ["fee"]=>
    string(4) "0.04"
    ["executed"]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-05 03:04:21"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["currency_pair"]=>
    string(6) "BTCCAD"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "Buy"
    ["trade_id"]=>
    string(5) "34631"
    ["order_id"]=>
    string(8) "51183954"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(10) "0.47688340"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "271.45"
    ["total"]=>
    string(6) "129.45"
    ["fee"]=>
    string(4) "0.54"
    ["executed"]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-04 23:19:09"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    ["currency_pair"]=>
    string(6) "BTCCAD"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "Buy"
    ["trade_id"]=>
    string(5) "34630"
    ["order_id"]=>
    string(8) "51169904"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(10) "0.25000000"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "272.63"
    ["total"]=>
    string(5) "68.16"
    ["fee"]=>
    string(4) "0.29"
    ["executed"]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-04 21:45:01"
  }
}
```

I want to iterate through array, taking the values of each key (e.g., "currency_pair", "type", "trade_id", etc.) and plugging them into a mysql table.

```html
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    
    $datetime   = $data['executed'];
    $currency_pair  = $data['currency_pair'];
    $type    = $data['type'];
    $quantity   = $data['quantity'];
    $rate    = $data['price'];
    $total    = $data['total'];
    $fee    = $data['fee'];

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "password";
 $dbname = "myDB";
 
 $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 
 
 // create connection
 if (!$connection) {
  die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 } else {
  echo "connected! ";
 }
 
 // sql to create table
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Transactions (type)
 VALUES ('$type')";
 
 if (mysqli_query($connnection, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connnection);
}
 
} 
mysqli_close($connection);
```

I'm only trying to insert 'types' into the database in the example above. I get two errors:

1) PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: connnection in

2) PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Comment: You `foreach`, and if you will have any problem with that, tell us what problem exactly you have.

Comment: Honestly, I have no good ideas about how to do it.

Comment: all you have to do is to convert your json into and php array like `$yourArray = json_decode(yourjson);` and then use `foreach` to insert all records to the database

Comment: I'm having a problem with the foreach loop to go over the array.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Your JSON is not valid, the upper curly brackets should be square brackets.

should be like:

```
[ 
    {
        "date" : "May 12",
        "id" : "20",
        "type" : "tall"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "May 14",
        "id" : "30",
        "type" : "short"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "May 17",
        "id" : "70",
        "type" : "giant"
    }
]
```

You can make your JSON source correct or strip your response first and last character and wrap in square brackets like:

```
$json_response = '['.substr(trim($response), 1, -1).']';
```

there after do [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and loop through

```
$json_array = json_decode($json_response);
if(!empty(json_response)){
    foreach ($json_response as $key => $value) {
        // Do Something!
    }
}
```